# How to load data from a different class in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class

I am quite a beginner in iPhone programming so this might be a noob question but here it is:

I am making an app which draws a couple of paths on a Google map. The paths are quiet long and require a lot of coordinates as they have bends in them. I want to know if there is a way I could store the coordinates in a different file or class so i could call "make path" from the main implementation file and it  would make the path from the coordinates that are stored in a coordinates.m file for example, or anything like that. I want to do this just so that the code is easier to read.

Thnaks!

Comment: The simple answer is, "Yes you can...good idea!" :)  The more complicated part (if you want to do it well) involves understanding the model-view-controller concept.  If you search for some information on MVC (especially the 'M' part), it should give you some good ways to design this.

Comment: I will definetly have a look in that, thank you! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at subclassing NSObject to make your own custom class that could 'define' a map path. You could then build in a `saveToFile:` and `loadFromFile:` method. Then you can just choose a file format to save you data to. The easiest might be .dat files for which you use [NSKeyedArchiver](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/), this is good for small files. Or you could use a differnt format like .plist files.

Like @Phillip Mills said, it is important to understand the MVC design paradigm before designing any apple apps.